# How to set header with busybox httpd

Tags: busybox

I am running busybox httpd with following command:

`busybox httpd -p 80 -h /var/www`

It works, however I need to set cache-control header to no cache.

Currently my server append only these headers:

```
  HTTP/1.0 200 OK
  Content-type: text/html
  Date: Thu, 28 Jun 2018 06:58:08 GMT
  Connection: close
  Accept-Ranges: bytes
  Last-Modified: Thu, 28 Jun 2018 06:57:43 GMT
  Content-Length: 45
```

How can I configure my busybox httpd server to append

`Cache-Control: no-cache`

header?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BusyBox HTTP Daemon (httpd) webserver is an own simple web server implementation without wide configuration options, as you can see from the [OpenWRT configuration documentation](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/services/webserver/http.httpd#configuration) or the comment block from [`httpd.c`](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/networking/httpd.c) source (lines 39-60):

```
 * httpd.conf has the following format:
 *
 * H:/serverroot     # define the server root. It will override -h
 * A:172.20.         # Allow address from 172.20.0.0/16
 * A:10.0.0.0/25     # Allow any address from 10.0.0.0-10.0.0.127
 * A:10.0.0.0/255.255.255.128  # Allow any address that previous set
 * A:127.0.0.1       # Allow local loopback connections
 * D:*               # Deny from other IP connections
 * E404:/path/e404.html # /path/e404.html is the 404 (not found) error page
 * I:index.html      # Show index.html when a directory is requested
 *
 * P:/url:[http://]hostname[:port]/new/path
 *                   # When /urlXXXXXX is requested, reverse proxy
 *                   # it to http://hostname[:port]/new/pathXXXXXX
 *
 * /cgi-bin:foo:bar  # Require user foo, pwd bar on urls starting with /cgi-bin/
 * /adm:admin:setup  # Require user admin, pwd setup on urls starting with /adm/
 * /adm:toor:PaSsWd  # or user toor, pwd PaSsWd on urls starting with /adm/
 * /adm:root:*       # or user root, pwd from /etc/passwd on urls starting with /adm/
 * /wiki:*:*         # or any user from /etc/passwd with according pwd on urls...
 * .au:audio/basic   # additional mime type for audio.au files
 * *.php:/path/php   # run xxx.php through an interpreter
```

Your options with BusyBox HTTPd:

- BusyBox HTTP Daemon is open source. Modify [`httpd.c`](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/networking/httpd.c) to add the header and compile.
- Have your page served as a [cgi script](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/services/webserver/http.httpd#cgi_scripts). It can have custom headers at the beginning.

Or install some more versatile web server that has this: [Nginx](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html), [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html), [Lighttpd](https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/Docs_ModSetEnv)...

Comment: Is it possible to configure httpd to run cgi script for all request? From what I read, it does not seems to be possible (perhaps I am missing something???).

Comment: The configuration is limited to what's quoted here. You can do everything you want, but not through configuration, but through modifying the source code. It's much easier and sensible to add a single header than to modify the behavior with CGI scripts.

Answer (score -1):

```
docker run -d --name busybox-http -p 8080:8080 -e TZ=UTC-8 busybox sh -c "
echo GMT-8 > /etc/TZ
mkdir -p /root/cgi-bin
cat > /root/cgi-bin/a.html <<EOF
#!/bin/sh
echo -e 'Content-Type: text/plain\n'
echo \"hostname=[\\\$(hostname)], time=[\\\$(date '+%F %T')], query=[\\\${QUERY_STRING}], path=[\\\${PATH_INFO}]\"
echo \"requestUrl=[\\\${REQUEST_URI}]\"
echo -e \"\n=== env list:\n\\\$(env|sed 's/\n/<br>/g')\"
EOF
chmod u+x /root/cgi-bin/a.html
httpd -p 8081 -h /root
cat > /root/httpd.conf <<EOF
P:/:http://localhost:8081/cgi-bin/a.html/
EOF
httpd -p 8080 -c /root/httpd.conf
sleep infinty
"
```

```
curl localhost:8080/a/b?c=1
```

Result Output:

```
hostname=[e95c54e5ff19], time=[2021-01-19 23:20:42], query=[c=1], path=[/a/b]
requestUrl=[/cgi-bin/a.html/a/b?c=1]

=== env list:
GATEWAY_INTERFACE=CGI/1.1
HOSTNAME=e95c54e5ff19
SHLVL=2
REMOTE_ADDR=[::ffff:127.0.0.1]
HOME=/root
QUERY_STRING=c=1
HTTP_USER_AGENT=curl/7.29.0
REMOTE_PORT=51456
HTTP_ACCEPT=*/*
SCRIPT_FILENAME=/root/cgi-bin/a.html
HTTP_HOST=localhost:8080
REQUEST_URI=/cgi-bin/a.html/a/b?c=1
SERVER_SOFTWARE=busybox httpd/1.31.1
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
SERVER_PROTOCOL=HTTP/1.0
PATH_INFO=/a/b
REQUEST_METHOD=GET
PWD=/root/cgi-bin
SCRIPT_NAME=/cgi-bin/a.html
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation as to how this answers the question?

Comment: ... and please do some formatting also, it's hard to even read your answer as it is